# Extension Library Update Issue

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to have my Notes Admin update to the latest Extension Library release. We already have an update site on the server. We are at the following step:

- Select the Import Local Update Site button in this
  application and select site.xml file from an Eclipse plugin project extracted from the
  “updateSiteOpenNTF.zip” or “updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip” archive files. Pressing the
  OK button begins the import process. And the view of the update site database will be
  updated with a document representing the import of the plugins.

But, when we try this, we get an error:

- Site import has failed, the database has been restored to its previous state. Check the activity log for details.

The activity log is below:

- 3/23/2015 3:28:14 PM  Initiated by Name/Org (using Release 9.0.1)
- 3/23/2015 3:28:14 PM  Importing site C:\Users\name\Desktop\ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00_11.20141217-1000\updateSiteOpenNTF\site.xml
- 3/23/2015 3:28:15 PM  The existing category doc for 'OpenNTF Builds' is already uptodate
- 3/23/2015 3:28:16 PM  Creating new plugin doc for 'plugins/org.apache.wink_1.1.2.20141217-1000.jar'
- 3/23/2015 3:30:15 PM  Site import has failed, the database has been restored to its previous state. Check the activity log for details.
- 3/23/2015 3:30:15 PM  Couldn't get default View id for database (UpdateSite1.nsf) (#4175) in:
- lsclasssitefeature: cmanagepluginrefs::rendertable (line 1463)<-----
- lsclasssitefeature: cmanagepluginrefs::fixup (line 1243)
- lsclasssitefeature: csitefeature::serialize (line 587)
- 3/23/2015 3:30:15 PM  Activity completed

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve? Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some details of your client/server version you are using as 9.0.1FP3 had some issues with updatesites. Also: I strongly recommend you to use the OpenNTF Updatesite template as it allows you to DELETE existing features instead of just DISABLING. You can find the template here: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Open%20Eclipse%20Update%20Site

Comment: The server and client are both on 9.0.1FP3. Does this mean we cannot update Extension Library using an Update Site?

Comment: I am not sure but what I heard installing IF1 for FP3 and also the JVM patch will help - this is a client issue only with plain FP3. JVM patches can be found here http://www.ponte.ch/blog/ibm-notesdomino-security-bulletin-vulnerabilities-in-the-ibm-java-sdk/ , IF1 is in fixcentral.

Comment: I was wrong, you should install  JVM patch for SR16FP3 to make this work. And this fix will be included in FP4.

Comment: details here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21698222

Comment: I had the Notes Admin install the JVMPatch_SR16FP3_W32_901.3_ClientServer (9.0.1.3_ClientServer_w32_JVM_Patch_20150303_142321.exe) on his client and it hasn't fixed the issue. Does this need to be installed on the server as well?

Comment: @OliverBusse - We loaded the OpenNTF Update Site and it seemed to fix this problem. Thanks.